# Class instance in Python

Tags: python, oop, class

I have problem with using class instance in Python.
Ive created a new class ora which inherit connect class from cx_Oracle package.
When  I try tu run this code I recive information

File "pyt.py", line 12, in myquery
    ora.myConnect.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

So Python cannote recognize that in ora.myConnect  is stored reference to instance.
I don`t know what can be reason of this error and what it`s wrong with code.

```
from cx_Oracle import connect

class ora(connect):
  myConnect = None

  def __init__(self,connstr):    
    ora.myConnect = connect.__init__(self,connstr)


  def myquery(self):
      ora.myConnect.cursor()
      ora.myConnect.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
      ora.myConnect.cursor.close()   



connstr = 'user/passwd@host:port/sid' 
connection = ora(connstr)      
connection.myquery()                 
connection.close()
```

EDIT

I`ve tried to replace ora to self but still Python don`t have access to instance

```
from cx_Oracle import connect

class ora(connect):
  myConnect = None

  def __init__(self,connstr):    
    self.myConnect = connect.__init__(self,connstr)
  def myquery(self):
      self.myConnect.cursor()
      self.myConnect.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
      self.myConnect.cursor.close()
```

Error:
    self.myConnect.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

EDIT2
This code works without OOP, for me self.myConnect sholud reference to object instance and this object should contain method cursor()

```
import cx_oracle
connstr = 'user/passwd@host:port/sid' 
connection = cx_oracle.connect(connstr)                   
cursor = connection.cursor()                              
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: `self.myConnect = connect.__init__(self,connstr)` is odd. It seems unlikely that the `__init__` method should return a cursor. Are you sure you understand how the class you're extending is supposed to work?

Comment: Based on [the documentation here](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect) I would say you're not really supposed to extend `connect` as you have done. Instead, just call `cx_Oracle.connect()` from your `__init__` and save the connection as `self.myConnect`.

Comment: self.myConnect sholud return reference to object instance,
for example without OOP this code works
import cx_oracle
connstr = 'user/passwd@host:port/sid' 
connection = cx_oracle.connect(connstr)                   
cursor = connection.cursor()                              
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
cursor.close()
connection.close()

Comment: I've updated my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @beerbajay Your method without inherit works also great thnks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want `self`:

```
class ora(connect):
    myConnect = None

    def __init__(self, connstr):    
        self.myConnect = connect.__init__(self, connstr)

    # ...
```

`ora` is the name of the class, not the instance.

**Update** Try the following:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect

class ora:
    myConnect = None

    def __init__(self, connstr):    
        self.myConnect = connect(connstr)

    def myquery(self):
        self.myConnect.cursor()
        self.myConnect.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
        self.myConnect.cursor.close()
```

Comment: If you replace `ora` with `self` in `__init__` and `myquery`, your `connection` object should be functional. What error are you getting?

Comment: I had a problem with comments fromating, so I`ve added more details in first post

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want `self.myConnect` to refer to the `connect` instance? That's a complete misunderstanding of OOP. The `ora` instance **is** the `connect` instance. `self.cursor` is where you find the cursor.

Here's how your code should look:

```
class ora(connect):

  def __init__(self,connstr):    
    super(ora, self).__init__(connstr)

  def myquery(self):
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
    self.cursor.close()
```

In any case, `__init__` must never return anything, so setting `self.myConnect` to the return value will always result in it being bound to `None`.

Comment: Thanks - I don`t knew about this metod super, now it works great